# Center text to bottom in grid area

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-grid

I'm a bit new to HTML and CSS but I'm trying to learn grids. I have a background in WPF which heavily uses grids. It's mostly straightforward but I'm confused on how to align  to the bottom of it's area.

AccountBar.js

```
<div className={styles.container}>
    <img className={styles.avatar} style={{backgroundImage: `url(${profileURL})`}}></img>
    <text className={styles.username}>Username</text>
    <text className={styles.discriminator}>#1337</text>
</div>
```

style.module.css

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
    'avatar username'
    'avatar discriminator';
}

.avatar {
    grid-area: avatar;
    background-image: url('https://tenor.com/view/pigeon-pidgeon-fire-eyes-burn-gif-24781901.gif');
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid #591496;
}

.username {
    grid-area: username;
    color: white;
}

.discriminator {
    grid-area: discriminator;
    color: white;
}
```

The result looks like so, but I'm trying to align "Username" to the bottom of it's cell.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is not from the grid but from element alignment. You can add `margin-top: auto;` (adding a top margin to cover all upper space and push your text to the bottom) to `.username` which would help you do the trick.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'avatar username'
    'avatar discriminator';
  background-color: #ccc; /*For testing*/
}

.avatar {
  grid-area: avatar;
  background-image: url('https://tenor.com/view/pigeon-pidgeon-fire-eyes-burn-gif-24781901.gif');
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #591496;
}

.username {
  grid-area: username;
  color: white;
  margin-top: auto; /*The change is here*/
}

.discriminator {
  grid-area: discriminator;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img class="avatar" style="background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg');"/>
    <text class="username">Username</text>
    <text class="discriminator">#1337</text>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah that works perfect, thanks for explaining as well. I have one additional question if that's okay. How could I make it so the cells only take up the minimum amount of width? As in there's a lot of whitespace in the cells.

Answer (score 1):

A few solutions here:

### Easy ones:

#### Because you are using `display: grid` set `align-self: flex-end` in `.username`

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'avatar username' 'avatar discriminator';
  background: gray
}

.avatar {
  grid-area: avatar;
  background-image: url('https://tenor.com/view/pigeon-pidgeon-fire-eyes-burn-gif-24781901.gif');
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #591496;
}

.username {
  grid-area: username;
  color: white;
  align-self: flex-end
}

.discriminator {
  grid-area: discriminator;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="avatar" src="https://tenor.com/view/pigeon-pidgeon-fire-eyes-burn-gif-24781901.gif">
  <text class="username">Username</text>
  <text class="discriminator">#1337</text>
</div>
```

#### Set `margin-top: auto` in `.username`

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'avatar username' 'avatar discriminator';
  background: gray
}

.avatar {
  grid-area: avatar;
  background-image: url('https://tenor.com/view/pigeon-pidgeon-fire-eyes-burn-gif-24781901.gif');
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #591496;
}

.username {
  grid-area: username;
  color: white;
  margin-top: auto
}

.discriminator {
  grid-area: discriminator;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="avatar" src="https://tenor.com/view/pigeon-pidgeon-fire-eyes-burn-gif-24781901.gif">
  <text class="username">Username</text>
  <text class="discriminator">#1337</text>
</div>
```

---

### Complex ones (not necessarily need to use these)

#### Use `display: grid` and `align-content: flex-end` in `.username`

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'avatar username' 'avatar discriminator';
  background: gray
}

.avatar {
  grid-area: avatar;
  background-image: url('https://tenor.com/view/pigeon-pidgeon-fire-eyes-burn-gif-24781901.gif');
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #591496;
}

.username {
  grid-area: username;
  color: white;
  display: grid;
  align-content: flex-end
}

.discriminator {
  grid-area: discriminator;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="avatar" src="https://tenor.com/view/pigeon-pidgeon-fire-eyes-burn-gif-24781901.gif">
  <text class="username">Username</text>
  <text class="discriminator">#1337</text>
</div>
```

#### Use `display: flex; flex-direction: column` and `justify-content: flex-end` in `.username`

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'avatar username' 'avatar discriminator';
  background: gray
}

.avatar {
  grid-area: avatar;
  background-image: url('https://tenor.com/view/pigeon-pidgeon-fire-eyes-burn-gif-24781901.gif');
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #591496;
}

.username {
  grid-area: username;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end
}

.discriminator {
  grid-area: discriminator;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="avatar" src="https://tenor.com/view/pigeon-pidgeon-fire-eyes-burn-gif-24781901.gif">
  <text class="username">Username</text>
  <text class="discriminator">#1337</text>
</div>
```